# three.js bind same texture multiple times with different wrapping/filterings

Tags: three.js

thanks for reading.

I have a WebGLRenderTarget that I render to.  At a subsequent stage in the rendering process I use that texture as input to a shader.

I would like to be able to use that same render target with multiple wrappings/filterings.  I have looked some at the internals of three.js, and am not sure that it is possible.

It seems like in webGL I would be able to just bind the same texture multiple times with different parameter settings.  I figure I can fork three.js to support a new type of texture that just uses another texture with new parameters, but wanted to see if there was some way I could do this without forking.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are correct. What you want to do is not supported for `WebGLRenderTarget`s. You can try cloning the render target, and then hacking the clone. three.js r.65.

Comment: what do you mean by "hacking the clone"?

Comment: Sorry, I was imprecise because I am not sure what the hack would be. The renderer adds private data to the render target, which would not be in the clone. You would have to inspect that data, and see if you could implement a work-around of some sort. If you figure it out, please share.

Comment: Yea, I have been looking through WebGLRenderer some.  It looks like with the way binding/updating textures work this wouldn't be possible.  Although I think it would be pretty easy to add a new type of texture and slightly modify the renderer to get the desired results.  This is probably the direction I'm headed in.  Thanks!